# Graph API - How long two users are friends

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to find how long or from when two users are friends to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out for future friends.  Just subscribe to the friend notification via Facebook's Real-time updates

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Store the collected information on when the friendship occurred in your data store.

Comment: should users subscribes to their friends notifications?

Comment: No, you app subscribes to the real-time updates for you apps users.  Then you track it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this is by pulling the live information of a user, and then do a diff on the friends list of each of your users, then store the changes in a `DateTime` field of some sort of DB.  However, I do believe that this is a violation of Facebook policy.

Comment: I didn't get you. How to get the live information of a user? If it is violating the facebook policy, isn't it graph api method?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ Read up on this.  Real-time updates will tell your servers when there is an update to the user (when they add friend for instance) and they you just store that information and keep a history of actions for all your users.  I tried to find the policy rules on this, but I was unable to do so.  So I don't know if it is against FB policy or not.